Ubuntu 24.04 and dash to panel extension
The panel from the Dash-to-panel extension is visible when my screen is locked and anyone can interact with the app context menus.
This really irks me.
Is someone having the same issue? Has anyone managed to fix this?

It is never reproducible when manually locking the screen (cmnd + L)
It is 100% reproducible when using suspend (simply type & run "suspend" from the activities)
Installed gnome runtimes:
$ sudo snap list | grep -i gnome
gnome-3-34-1804                       0+git.3556cb3        93     latest/stable    canonical**     -
gnome-3-38-2004                       0+git.efb213a        143    latest/stable    canonical**     -
gnome-42-2204                         0+git.510a601        176    latest/stable    canonical**     -

Dash-to-Panel version: 62

Have you looked to see if there is any info on the Dash-to-panel extension site?

have you found the reason for that? Having the same struggle

Me too. I have my panel at the bottom.  When the display is powered off and then on both the side panel and bottom panel are displayed, the bottom missing out the system controls. When the system is suspended and restarts, awaiting a login, the side panel is back again and accessible.

Was able to get rid of the Ubuntu Dock by:

disabled the Dash to Panel extension in Extension Manager
enabled and disabled the Ubuntu Dock in Settings
enabled the Dash to Panel extension in Extension Manager

Locking the screen manually, or letting it lock automatically didn't enable the Ubuntu Dock so far. Hopefully it remains that way.
